# Unique marker ID for arraylist

Tags: android, google-maps, arraylist, google-maps-markers

What I am trying to do is when someone clicks on a marker on the google map, I need to get the info on that marker from my ArrayList and then pass it on to the next activity so I can display additional details about that marker. The only options that I know of when it comes to markers is getSnippet, getTitle and getPosition. Is there a way to assign a unique key to the marker so I can pull it from my list? Reason for this is there could be two markers with the same name. Right now it doesn't even find the marker by name when I do a search for it.

```
// WHEN A USER CLICKS A MAKER ON THE MAP
       @Override
   public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
   {
            // TESTING TO SEE WHAT MY VALUE WOULD BE IN THE LIST RETURNS - TEST MARKER             
            // DISPLAY ON SCREEN SO I CAN SEE WHAT THE VALUE IS
    Toast.makeText(this, "Found " + marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   // SEARCH MY LIST FOR VALUE
               for(int i = 0; i < marker_list.size(); i++) 
                {
                        // IF THIS VALUE IS SAME AS MARKER TITLE
                    String value = marker_list.get(i);

                    if(value == marker.getTitle()) 
                    {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Found " + value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `marker.toString()` ? 
Instead of using an `ArrayList` to store the markers and running through the list to find your value, you could use a `HashMap`. When you add your markers, you put `marker.toString()` as the key and whatever information you want to associate with the marker as the value into the `HashMap`.

By the way: you're method to find the clicked marker is probably not working because of the way you compare `Strings`:

```
value == marker.getTitle()
```

This checks if two `String` references are the exact same `String object`. To compare the `String values`, do

```
 value.equals(marker.getTitle())
```

Comment: Yes value.equals fixed my problem as far as the search. I think the best way to do this is by making the snippet my ID number then finding it. Is there a way to hide the snippet but it still be there so I can reference it but user does not see it?

Comment: I don't think you can hide the snippet. Plus you would have to set it yourself, while marker.toString() 'works' automatically.

Comment: I did find a way to hide it. Using InfoWindowAdapter and setInfoWindowAdapter() .. Seems to work really well, but your answer did help me with the search so I have accepted it. Thanks for your help.